# Unable to post byte array to webservices (REST) in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, post, arrays, asihttprequest

I am developing an application which requiers me to convert an audio/video/image file into a 'BYTE ARRAY' and upload that to web services(REST) through a POST request. I am actually using `ASIHTTPRequest` (`ASIFormData`) to POST the data. But I could not find any class/method which will allow me to post the `byteArray`. Is there a way to do this....?

Comment: Did you got the solution ? Can you please share ?

Comment: Did you got the solution ? Can you please share ?

Answer (score 2):

You can post any data with ASIFormDataRequest's setData. [Here's](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) an example.

Comment: ASI will send it as a byte array.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an `NSData` out of your bytes, and set that to the request using `setData:`.

[NSData Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithBytes%3alength%3a)

Comment: setData accepts only NSData object. But i need to send bytes to my server

Comment: `NSData` is just a OO wrapper around byte arrays.

Comment: But the backend server accepts only byteArray... Even though NSData is a OO wrapper around byte array, the internal structure of both differ... Any thoughts?

Comment: ASI will take care of serializing it while preparing the request body.